# Convert XML file to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a requirement to convert many XMLF files in a folder (in zip format) to a data frame. All the discussion on Stack Overflow, are based on databricks. As I am not using databricks, I cannot use their approach.

Is there a way to do the same?

**What I tried :**

I unzipped the file and tried to directly read it :

```
df_schema = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "Root").load("test.xml")
```

**Error message :**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xml.DefaultSource
```

Do I need to install anything to fix the issue? Or do I need to convert the XML to CSV via Python and read in data frame?

Comment: Hope xml packages are installed correctly ?

Comment: hi, i am using sagemaker-pyspark on aws. i am assuming it shoudl have all packages or libraries. i  can install if required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install the spark-xml Scala libraries. You can include them via Maven coordinates in a Spark job. https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#scala-212